# When code in functions.php executes in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new in wordpress.

I have added function in functions.php file of child theme. This function creates post in database. When this code will run (In other when post will create in db)?

I did google but couldn't find this.

I WANT TO PUBLISH POST VIA CODE

Comment: If it's just thrown in `functions.php` it'll run on every page load. If it's in a function within that file, it'll never run unless you write code somewhere to execute it.

Comment: @ceejayoz -  It is a function in functions.php file. From where can I call this function?

Comment: Wherever you like. Decide when **you** want it to run and act accordingly.

Comment: @ceejayoz - I am asking about php file from which I can call

Comment: Once you've written a function, you then need to pick [which WordPress action should trigger that function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). Which one you pick depends entirely on what your function does and when you want it to run, which you haven't given us any info on.

Comment: @ceejayoz- I just want to execute this function once in a day

Comment: Then you probably want to write a plugin, not a theme function, and you'll want to read https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event.

Comment: @CuteSparrow WordPress scheduled events will only fire if the website is accessed.  A once-a-day event will require traffic to the site or a server cron.

Comment: @ceejayoz - if I create post from external script then what location should I put my script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress loads files in this order:

1. WordPress Core
2. Plugins
3. Parent Theme
4. Child Theme

`functions.php` is the first file that loads in a theme.  It runs every time a page loads.

Comment: if I create post from external script then what location should I put my script?.

Comment: I would add the script with an `include` like this:  `include( locate_template( 'path-to-script.php' ) );`